# Detect and delete spam email with Mac/Mail software

Tags: macos, email, apple-mail, spam-prevention

I keep receiving the following email.
It changes the sender, and contents a little bit all the time, so my spam filter doesn't filter it out.

Is there any way to find this pattern to filter it out?

```
My=Friend-Is=Looking-ForYou~On=TheWeb?~She~Likes~Your~Photos .,.


http://2su.de/S0w






---------------
the ought, inhumanity go sulphuret.
No therefore. At do partner, shape! That easy-chair sympathetic.
```

Comment: i tagged "mail.app" on the assumption you're using that on Mac OS X.  go ahead and change it if you're using another email client.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I have ever done this myself (I use gmail), if you are using mail.app in Mac OS, you can add a rule to move emails with that URL in them to your trash:

```
  If  ANY  of the following conditions are met:

   MESSAGE CONTENT    CONTAINS  http://2su.de/S0w

  Perform the following actions:

   MOVE MESSAGE  to mailbox:  TRASH
```

You can add the rule by going into the menu bar and selecting Mail/Preferences and then in the preferences window, click on the "Rules" icon in the upper right area.

This assumes that the URL is a constant in these messages.  If not, look for something else that is in common and set the rule to filter that.

Comment: You should probably also enable junk mail filtering in preferences.  If you can't find anything consistent to filter on, then you may have to go to a 3rd party anti-spam tool.  I'm not familiar with what's available for the Mac, but I'm sure you can google for it.